# Quitar caracteres y letras en Pandas

Tags: python, caracteres

Debo iterar sobre una columna y eliminar los caracteres especiales y las letras. ¿Alguna idea? El asunto es que no siempre esta al inicio de la cadena.

EJEMPLO:

```
PC 17572
546RT*5
```

RESULTADO:

```
17527
5465
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `.map()` sobre esa columna, pasándole una función que haga el trabajo de quedarse sólo con los caracteres que sean dígitos. No tengo muy claro si quieres que lo que te retorne sea otra cadena, o si quieres el valor numérico final. Supondré lo primero.

Una función así podría ser la siguiente, que recibe una cadena como `"X-223A* 14"` y te retorna otra cadena como `"22314"`.

```
def dejar_solo_cifras(txt):
  return "".join(c for c in txt if c.isdigit())
```

Esta función se puede aplicar a todos los elementos de una columna mediante `.map()`, como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"datos": ["PC 17572",
                                 "546RT*5"]})
>>> df
      datos
0  PC 17572
1   546RT*5
>>> df.datos = df.datos.map(dejar_solo_cifras)
>>> df
   datos
0  17572
1   5465
```

Comment: Hola, estuve intentando aplicar tu sugerencia pero no me funciona, te comento, tengo un dataset, con una columna llamada ticket, en esa columna hay 1538 registros combinados con letras , numeros y caracteres especiales. lo que deseo es que me recorra toda la columna y me devuelva dicha columna con solo los datos numericos..

Comment: for k in data_tres['ticket']:

Comment: for k in data_tres['ticket']: aqui recorro  la columna, AQUI REEMPLAZO data_tres['ticket']=data_tres['ticket'].replace('A-Z','  ',regex=False), pero no me hace nada

Comment: ¿Y por qué dices que no funciona la solución propuesta? ¿te da error? ¿no cambia alguno de los datos? Yo la he probado con varios casos y va bien. Lo que propones de usar regexp es otra posibilidad, pero tu regexp es incorrecta y sobra el bucle (pandas ya aplica replace a cada elemento de la columna sin necesidad de for)

Comment: Hola!! listo! el error estaba en otra parte del codigo, era una llamada incorrecta a una fucion.... ya lo pude solventar, tu idea  me ayudo a encontrar ese detalle!!! @abulafia Gracias!!!!!!!

Comment: @rosedewitt Entonces ¿respuesta aceptada? Marca el ✓ para señalarlo en ese caso.

Comment: Si! gracias!!!!